# What code does a task like the reshape2 package in a base reshape function?

Tags: r, reshape2

I'm learning reshape function(base R) that works like reshape2 package of hadley wickham.
I wrote the code below using `reshape2` package.

```
melt(iris, id.vars = 'Species')
```

The result :
column names are Species , variable, value and entire number of the result is 600

I wrote this code

```
reshape(iris, idvar = 'Species', direction = 'long')
```

But show error message

> Error in reshape(iris, idvar = "Species", direction = "long") :   "no
>   'reshapeWide' attribute, must specify 'varying'

How to see the same result that perform `melt` function in `reshape2` package?

Comment: Hi Jh J, FYI, Those packages are not in base; both `reshape` and `reshape2` package are by Hadley. And both packages are superseded by the `tidyr` library, containing `gather()` and `spread()`. see https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: The `reshape` function is in base R.  `find("reshape")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck you are correct, I mixed-up the base function `stats::reshape()` and the `reshape::melt()` package.

Answer (score 2):

Specify at least `varying` and preferably all those shown:

```
nm <- names(iris)[-5]
long <- reshape(iris, dir = "long",
  varying = list(nm), times = nm, timevar = "Attribute", v.names = "value")
```

The first few rows of `long` are:

```
> head(long)
               Species    Attribute value id
1.Sepal.Length  setosa Sepal.Length   5.1  1
2.Sepal.Length  setosa Sepal.Length   4.9  2
3.Sepal.Length  setosa Sepal.Length   4.7  3
4.Sepal.Length  setosa Sepal.Length   4.6  4
5.Sepal.Length  setosa Sepal.Length   5.0  5
6.Sepal.Length  setosa Sepal.Length   5.4  6
```