# Can reshape in base R turn more than one time var into a single columns in long format?

Tags: r, runtime-error

I can reshape the part of my columns having the same 'name stem' `opg.1` through `opg.10`, but when I present the last two 'time' variables, `mkd.1` and `mkd.2`, I get the following error:

```
Fejl i reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  : 
  'varying' arguments must be the same length
```

In short, my question is, will renaming `mkd.1` and `mkd.2` to have the same `opg` name stem remove the error, and in case it will, why?

My code is

```
gdata <- termin.test[sel.cols]
names(gdata) <- c(  "opg.1", "opg.2","opg.3","opg.4","opg.5", "opg.61",
                    "opg.62","opg.7","opg.8","opg.9","opg.10",
                    "navn",
                    "mkd.11","mkd.12"  )
head(gdata)
#   opg.1 opg.2 opg.3 opg.4 opg.5 opg.61 opg.62 opg.7 opg.8 opg.9 opg.10
# 1     2     2     0     0     1      0     10     4     5    10      3
# 2     0     1     0     0     2      2      5     5     2     8      1
# 3     1     0     0     0     0      0      7     3     3     7      4
# 4     0     0     0     0     0      2      7     4     8    10      7
# 5     8     2     3     4     7      3     11    12    10     8     16
# 6     1     2     1     1     2      2      5     2     2     3      6
#        navn mkd.11 mkd.12
# 1  Czzzzzzz      5     24
# 2  Xxxxxx A      2     16
# 3  Cccccc B      1     17
# 4 Christian      0     26
# 5 Emil Xxxx     16     33
# 6 Aaaaa-Sss      4     11
```

So far so good. But here, my `varying=` parameter turns me down.
I wanted the variables `opg.1`-`opg.10` **and** the final two `mkd.11` and  `mkd.12`.

```
redata <- reshape(
  # De første 11 kolonner er opgave-kryd-optællinger + nr 12: Elevens navn
  gdata, # [,1:12], 
  direction = "long",
  varying=c(1:11,13,14), # Works problem free with   varying = 1:11
  timevar = "opgave", # 
  # Vektor OPGAVER er defineret med opgavenavne ovenfor  ????
  times = opgaver
)
```

I have a hypothesis that it will work to rename  `mkd.11` ->  `opg.11`. But I post the question, because I  would like to (1) get into base R and (2) comprehend what I am doing. I looked up the question [What code does a task like the reshape2 package in a base reshape function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57638567/4832261) but did not find neither a matching problem posed nor answers relevant to my question.

### Edit

Rephrasing the question as I need a single numerical column in the long format reshaped data frame.

Comment: try with `varying = list(1:11, 13, 14)`

Comment: My problem with cols #13 and #14 is that I need to avoid empty cells, `NA`s.

Comment: updated with ggplot as well

Comment: You have to use `varying = list(c(1:11, 13, 14))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reshape` function needs the "varying" argument to have balanced and consistent names. opg has 11 items and mkd has only 2.

> I need a single numerical column in the long format reshaped data
>   frame.

Then rename the two mkd variables to `opg.11` and `opg.12` before reshaping (as you did).

```
names(gdata)[13:14] <- c("opg.11","opg.12")

reshape(gdata,
  direction = "long",
  varying=c(1:11,13,14),
  timevar = "opgave"  
  )  # we don't have your `opgaver` object

          navn opgave opg id
1.1   Czzzzzzz      1   2  1
2.1   Xxxxxx A      1   0  2
3.1   Cccccc B      1   1  3
4.1  Christian      1   0  4
5.1  Emil Xxxx      1   8  5
6.1  Aaaaa-Sss      1   1  6
...
1.12  Czzzzzzz     12  24  1
2.12  Xxxxxx A     12  16  2
3.12  Cccccc B     12  17  3
4.12 Christian     12  26  4
5.12 Emil Xxxx     12  33  5
6.12 Aaaaa-Sss     12  11  6
```

If your output is a boxplot, then modify the labels in the command to draw it, or you can convert the `opgave` variable into a factor with the appropriate labels.

Comment: Your explanations help me understanding. My wording and the content of the question witness that I am new to R, but grateful that both of you could spare your time for my problem, despite poor wording.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to rename the 'mkd' to 'opg'

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gdata %>% 
    rename_at(vars(starts_with('mkd')), ~ str_replace(., 'mkd', 'opg')) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -navn, names_to = 'opgave', values_to = 'value') %>%
    ggplot(aes(x =opgave, y = value)) +
       geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

#### data

```
gdata <- structure(list(opg.1 = c(2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 8L, 1L), opg.2 = c(2L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L), opg.3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L), opg.4 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L), opg.5 = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 2L), opg.61 = c(0L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L), opg.62 = c(10L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 5L), opg.7 = c(4L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 2L), opg.8 = c(5L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 2L), opg.9 = c(10L, 
8L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 3L), opg.10 = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 16L, 6L), navn = c("Czzzzzzz", 
"Xxxxxx A", "Cccccc B", "Christian", "Emil Xxxx", "Aaaaa-Sss"
), mkd.11 = c(5L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 16L, 4L), mkd.12 = c(24L, 16L, 
17L, 26L, 33L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: It might show from my usage of the reshaped data frame that I need to avoid `NA`s. One day, I may be able to read and understand your addition. In your base R suggestion, I get `mkd.2` and `mkd.3` columns (started out with `mkd.1` and `mkd.2`?) adn they are filled with `NA`s only.

Comment: @Engelsmann I ithink the column names are still not in order.  I didn't get the chance to put that in correct order.  If you do it in the order for both 'mkd' and 'opg', it should work i.e. if a mkd.1 doesn't have a correspoonding 'opg.1 non -NA value, it would be NA

Answer (score 1):

I can see that when I use the suggestion of @akrun, I get two columns `opg` and `mkd` in the reshaped data frame, and as there are 11 `opg`-columns and only 2 `mkd`-cols the reason for the mentinoed error message is evident: in my data set, I end up with

```
> melt(setDT(gdata), measure = patterns('^opg\\.\\d+$', '^mkd\\.\\d+$'),
+            value.name = c('opg', 'mkg'), variable.name = 'opgave')
#                  navn opgave opg mkg
#  1:          Czzzzzzz      1   2   5
#  2:    Caroline Cxxxx      1   0   2
#  3:    Crrrrrrr Rrrrr      1   1   1
#  4:         Christian      1   0   0
#  5:    Emil Zzzz Cccc      1   8  16
# ---                                                 
#238:            Owiler     11   8  NA
#239:              Sarah    11   5  NA
#240:          Bang Bang    11  10  NA
#241:             Thhhhh    11   2  NA
#242:          William B    11   6  NA
```

The `NA` values in the `mkg` column show that there are fewer variables of this type. This is not as intended. Therefore I stick to the same-name-stem option:

```
gdata <- termin.test[sel.cols]
names(gdata) <- c(  "opg.1", "opg.2","opg.3","opg.4","opg.5", "opg.61",
                    "opg.62","opg.7","opg.8","opg.9","opg.10",
                    "navn",
                    "opg.11","opg.12"  )
redata <- reshape(
  # De første 11 kolonner er opgave-kryd-optællinger + nr 12: Elevens navn
  gdata, # [,1:12], 
  direction = "long",
  varying=c(1:11,13,14),   # De første 11 kolonner skal "vendes"
  timevar = "opgave", # 
  # Vektor OPGAVER er defineret med opgavenavne ovenfor  ????
  times = opgaver
)
```

This solution works in my further processing in the diagram shown below using with `geom_boxplot()`, and I can live with the names of the two latter columns, or renaming them in the factored variable `opgave` is beyond the scope of this question.
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what your expected output wuold be so I showed `melt` and `pivot_longer`.  In the `pivot_longer`, it does the suffix match as well

Comment: And the options are nice to know. I shall add the final diagram to my answer. Your `NA`s in column `mkd` pointed me in the direction I needed, and explained the error message.